# Using trained TensorFlow model in Java

Tags: java, tensorflow

I have trained a TensorFlow model in Python and would like to use it in Java code. Training the model is done via something like this code:

```
def input_fn():
    features = {'a': tf.constant([[1],[2]]),
                'b': tf.constant([[3],[4]]) }
    labels = tf.constant([0, 1])
    return features, labels

feature_a = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature("a", bucket_size=10)
feature_b = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature("b", bucket_size=10)
feature_columns = [feature_a, feature_b]

model = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
model.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=10)
```

Now I want to save this model to use it in Java. It seems that export_savedmodel is the new/preferred way of saving, so I tried:

```
feature_spec = tf.contrib.layers.create_feature_spec_for_parsing(feature_columns)
serving_input_fn = input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn(feature_spec)
model.export_savedmodel('export', serving_input_fn, as_text=True)
```

This results in a saved model, which can be loaded from Java with

```
model = SavedModelBundle.load(dir, "serve");
model.session().runner()
    .feed("input_example_tensor", input)
    .fetch("linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/probabilities")
    .run();
```

There is now a problem though: the input_example_tensor should be a Tensor containing Strings/byte[]s, but this is not supported in Java yet (see: Tensor.java#88 "throw new UnsupportedOperationException"). As far as I understand it, the reason that it wants a String is that build_parsing_serving_input_fn wants to parse serialized Example protocol buffers.

Maybe a different serving_input_fn would do better.  `input_fn_utils.build_default_serving_input_fn` looks promising, but I didn't get that to work.

If I call it like:

```
features_dict = {'a':feature_a, 'b':feature_b}
serving_input_fn = input_fn_utils.build_default_serving_input_fn(features)
```

I get "AttributeError: '_SparseColumnIntegerized' object has no attribute 'get_shape'"

If I call it like:

```
features = {'a': tf.constant([[1],[2]]),
            'b': tf.constant([[3],[4]]) }
serving_input_fn = input_fn_utils.build_default_serving_input_fn(features)
```

I get "ValueError: 'Const:0' is not a valid scope name".

What is the proper way to use `input_fn_utils.build_default_serving_input_fn`? I can't find any example that uses it.

Comment: Didn't read your question very carefully, but I found this article which might be of some use :- https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-invoke-a-trained-tensorflow-model-from-java-programs-27ed5f4f502d

Comment: Link above way too old.